# Why cast used variable to void

Tags: c++, sse

I am currently looking through the OpenCV implementation of FAST and stumbled upon some variables which are cast to `void`. I understand that this is used to silence lint/compiler warnings, when a variable is not used. But in this case the variables are used. It might be related to SSE, since it only happens in those code parts.

```
#if CV_SSE2
    __m128i delta = _mm_set1_epi8(-128), t = _mm_set1_epi8((char)threshold), K16 = _mm_set1_epi8((char)K);
    (void)K16;
    (void)delta;
    (void)t;
#endif
```

Later usages (*edit*):

```
#if CV_SSE2
...
__m128i v1 = _mm_xor_si128(_mm_subs_epu8(v0, t), delta);
...
int m = _mm_movemask_epi8(_mm_cmpgt_epi8(max0, K16));
...
#endif
```

See also: full [fast.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/fast.cpp) in the OpenCV-Repository (the code I pasted is from line 71 onwards)

So, what is it good for and why only for SSE related variables?

Comment: It's just one of several ways of getting rid of compiler warnings (e.g. unused parameter, unused variable) when you know for certain that the warning is not a problem.

Comment: Is that done all over the code, or just for those 3 variables and not many if any others?

Comment: As far as I can see it's done for all variables that are exclusive to SSE and only for them. Those are also all in #if CV_SSE2 blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the blame for those lines, they were added in [this commit](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/46874d40dfb56560bc76936747400f76197f1a59), with commit message "*warnings under windows*".

You could ask the committer, https://github.com/CheeseWiz, but I'd suspect it just comes down to a bug in MSVC.

Comment: Looking into the commit messages was probably too obvious to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Though it's compiler dependent, it's typically used to surpress "unused variable" messages.

I prefer the `UNUSED(var)` macro, as it clearly shows the intent and can be customized to various compiler environments.

Comment: I understand that, but the variables *are* used, that's what confuses me.